# Unity3d FullScreen Mode Vertical Aspect Ratio in WebGl

Tags: unity, webgl, unity-webgl

My game has vertical aspect ratio and looks like this:

[image]

When I press full screen button

```
 <div class="webgl-content">
    <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 500px; height: 860px"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="fullscreen" onclick="gameInstance.SetFullscreen(1)"></div>
```

My game start to look like this:
[image]

I need to save aspect ratio of the game - how can I do that?

Comment: How do you lay out your content at present? Is it in a UI Canvas?

Comment: no, just id="gameContainer that's all

Comment: I mean inside your Unity project. How is your scene set up? **Walk us through the steps to build a sample game that demonstrates this problem, starting from a new, empty project**. That way we can test solutions to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: the most part of the game realized through canvas. another part of thegame change their aspect ratio, too. Canvas was configured in such way to it was good looking for this one resolutions 9:16 10:16 9:18

Comment: It sounds like you should familiarize yourself with the Canvas Scaler component: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-CanvasScaler.html